# Premiere Pro CC 2014 renders incredibly slow / Cineform

Tags: premiere, 3d, performance

I created a movie with Adobe Premiere Pro CC 2014 and I have serious performance issues when it comes to export the movie.

The first 10% renders pretty fast and takes 1 hour. Then it takes for every additional 1% about 4 hours! (never rendered it to finish so far, 14% max so far)

Here are some facts that might help to isolate the problem:

Project:

- **Length:** 24 minutes in total, splitted into several sequences (up to 4 minutes) and arranged on a "main-sequence"
- **Input:** Cineform AVI files, 1080p, 59fps (I converted GoPro 3+ footage (3D!) using GoPro Studio to the Cineform format for further processing)
- **Desired Output:** Same as input, preserving 3D (Render 3D Intermediate)
- **Effects  used**: Warp-Stabilizer (default settings) and Auto-Color (smoothing 1-2 sec) on almost every clip.

Hardware / Software:

- i7-3770K @3.5 GHZ (Quadcore)
- 16 GB RAM
- NVIDIA Geforce GTX 970 (also tried with a ATI Radeon R9 290X)
- Windows 8.1
- SSD for OS and programs, RAID 0 for media files and project, separate drive for rendering output.

Then I tried to render using AME using the same settings. The whole video rendered in about 14 hours what is acceptable in my case. There problem here is that the 3D gets lost, even if I selected "Render 3D Intermediate". The picture for the left eye is the same as the one for the right eye.
This is not happening when I do a direct export. But the direct export get almost stuck at around 10%.

There is almost no difference in choosing Software-Rendering and GPU. Also, the GPU has almost no load. 
Premiere Pro uses the CPU for about 45% (total usage 65%) and takes up 5-9 GB of memory (total usage 65%). Disk usage at around 14b/s.

I think there are two problems. One is that AME renders differently (no 3D) and the other is that the direct export takes way too long.

Can someone help me with any of these problems?

Thank you,

Martin

**Update 18.11.2014**

I did some additional research and found out, that the slow rendering happens with this combination:

- Auto-Color using Temporal Smoothing
- Render 3D Intermediate

Without rendering the 3D intermediate, Temporal Smoothing is not a problem. And without temporal smoothing, Rendering 3D Intermediate is not a problem.

Might this be a problem in the codec or in Premiere?

Comment: It may very well be.  Probably best to bring it to Adobe's support and see what they say.